# PowerApps: UpdateIf only updates first 100 records (SQL-Datasource)

Tags: sql, powerapps

i am trying to update a SQL-table with a button containing the function UpdateIf in PowerApps.
The button contains the following code:

```
UpdateIf(
    '[dbo].[INVINFO]',
    IVI_ID_NR = Dropdown_Inventur.Selected.Result && IVI_MANDANT = Dropdown_Mandant.Selected.Result,
    {IVI_ERFSET_MENGE: IVI_LAGER_IST - IVI_VORTRAG_MENGE}
)
```

My Problem is that it only updates the first 100 rows.
Based on the Dropdown-selection, 500-3000 rows should be updated.

I can't find anything about this 100-rows limitation in the Microsoft-documentation, so my question is: Am i doing anything wrong? Is there an alternative to UpdateIf? (i tried ForAll & Patch, but it was very slow, so i dumped it)

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this. I just made a stored procedure in the sql server that does this calculation. It works much faster and updates all rows, not just 100.